# Dynamically creating JSON objects from reflected methods

Tags: c#, json, rest, model-view-controller

I've since getting a bunch of help from the **SO** hivemind been able to create a REST API (C#, MVC) that handles dynamic (at least that's what I want to call it) calls through catching the string param and finding the correct method through using reflection.

```
 var myType = typeof(JaberoDC.JaberoDC.JaberoDC);


            var method = myType
                .GetMethods(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly)
                .Single(mi =>mi.ReturnType == typeof(DataSet) 
                && string.Equals(mi.Name, param, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
            var subject = Activator.CreateInstance(myType);
            var result = method.Invoke(subject, new Object[] { "", conStr, "", 0, 0, null });


            DataSet ds = (DataSet)result;
```

What I need help with now is any sort of advice on how to handle the various results dynamically. Meaning that I need some help with ***understanding*** how to either create a class that handles 0=>N columns from the rows in the DataTable (after getting the DT from the DS), or how to serialize the data without creating instances of above mentioned class.

Again, I'm sorry if my terminology is off here.

I've basically been thrown into the deep-end at my current employer to create a REST API for a DataComponent that has a few hundred methods. As it is now the API only works when using below code:

```
List<Worksite> arr2 = new List<Worksite>();

            foreach (DataTable table in ds.Tables)
            {

                foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
                {
                    string id = row["JobID"].ToString();
                    string name = row["JobName"].ToString();
                    string site = row["SiteName"].ToString();

                    arr2.Add(new Worksite
                    {
                        ID = id,
                        JobName = name,
                        SiteName = site
                    });
                }
            }
```

Basically this only handles **worksites** (a specific DataSet in the DataComponent).

**My current solution:**

```
 public string GetFromParam(String param)
        {

            var myType = typeof(JaberoDC.JaberoDC.JaberoDC);


            var method = myType
                .GetMethods(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly)
                .Single(mi =>mi.ReturnType == typeof(DataSet) 
                && string.Equals(mi.Name, param, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
            var subject = Activator.CreateInstance(myType);
            var result = method.Invoke(subject, new Object[] { "", conStr, "", 0, 0, null });


            DataSet ds = (DataSet)result;

            List<GenerateModel> arr2 = new List<GenerateModel>();
            int count = 0;

            List<Dictionary<string, object>> rows = new List<Dictionary<string, object>>();
            Dictionary <string, object> dicRow;
            foreach (DataTable table in ds.Tables)
            {
                foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
                {
                    dicRow = new Dictionary<string, object>();
                    foreach (DataColumn col in table.Columns){
                        dicRow.Add(col.ColumnName, row[col]);
                    }
                    rows.Add(dicRow);
                }

            }

//            for (int i = 0; i < ds.Tables.)

            string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(rows);
            return json;
        }
```

I'm basically using the proposed solution in the marked answer whilst also using a *dynamic* solution to the issue with datakey-value pairs by using a dictionary to hold them.

Comment: Have you looked at http://www.newtonsoft.com/json? it's a pretty decent library and should handle most of the types you're working with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with Clint's comment about using Json.net by Newtonsoft.  That has a lot of helper methods that will make your life easier.

Ideally, you will be creating one controller per type of data that you expect to receive.  Then you can use the incoming data to create an instance of a class that is modeled after what you will be receiving.  With RESTful APIs and MVC, I treat the incoming data as a FormDataCollection, which is like an incoming stream of keyvalue pairs that you must process sequentially.  Here is a code sample to point you in the right direction:

```
// POST api/mycontrollername
public HttpResponseMessage Post(FormDataCollection fdc)
{
    try
    {
        if (fdc != null)
        {
            MyClass myInstance = new MyClass();

            IEnumerator<KeyValuePair<string, string>> pairs = fdc.GetEnumerator();
            while (pairs.MoveNext())
            {
                switch (pairs.Current.Key)
                {
                    case "PhoneNumber":
                        myInstance.PhoneNumber = pairs.Current.Value;
                        break;
                    ...
                    default:
                        // handle any additional columns
                        break;
                }
            }

            // do stuff with myInstance
            // respond with OK notification
        }
        else
        {
            // respond with bad request notification
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // respond with internal server error notification
    }
}
```

If you must handle multiple data types with the same controller, there may be a particular data field that would give you a clue as to what you are receiving so that you can handle it appropriately.  If you genuinely have no idea what you are receiving at any time, you may be able to cast it as a dynamic type and use reflection, but it sounds like the data sender is setting you up for a tough integration in that case - it is definitely not how I would engineer an API...

EDIT: (To clarify based on your comments)  It appears you want to accept requests for any number of data types using a single controller, and return a DataTable with the results, even though you don't know in advance which fields the DataTable will contain.

First, unless it is a specific requirement, I wouldn't use a DataTable because it is not a very platform-independent solution - if the requesting application is in a non-.NET language, it will have an easier time parsing a Json array compared to a DataTable.  If you must use a DataTable, you can look into .Net's DataTable.ToXML() extension method, but I have run into issues with special characters not converting to XML well and some other gotchas with this approach.

If you want to go the recommended json route, the data you request will have to be sufficient to query the database (ie: RequestType = "jobSiteReport", MinDate = "7/1/2016", MaxDate = "7/12/2016").  Use this to query the database or generate the data (into a DataSet or DataTable if that is what you are comfortable with) depending on what the "RequestType" is.  Use Linq or a loop or some other method to transform the DataTable into an object array (this could be an anonymous type if you want, but I prefer keeping things strongly typed when I have the option.)  This is pseudocode, but should give you an idea of what I mean:

```
//using Newtonsoft.Json;

List<MyObject> objects = new List<MyObject>();
for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    MyObject obj = new MyObject()
    obj.Time = dt.Rows[i]["Time"];
    obj.Person = dt.Rows[i]["PersonID"];
    ...
    objects.Add(obj);
}

string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(objects.ToArray());
```

Now you have a string that contains json data with all of the results from your DataTable. Then you can return that.  (You could also use a SqlDataReader to accomplish the same result without using a DataTable as an intermediate step - populate the list from the SqlDataReader, convert the list to an array, then serialize the array to json.)

If you are inventing the schema, you should create documentation about what the requester should expect to receive.

Json.Net also has methods for deserializing strongly typed objects from json, deserializing anonymous types, etc.  You should read up on what is available - I'm sure that it has something that will be perfect for what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I do have sort of an idea of what to expect from the component, the problem is that I don't really know how MUCH I'm going to receive, meaning that I might receive 10 key-value pairs or 20 depending on what view / stored procedure I'm invoking. It's all a bit messy, but since the datacomponent has roughly 200 methods this might be easier than writing a separate class to handle each method...

Comment: You might try populating any mandatory fields into your model object and then creating a dictionary to store any optional fields - in the "default" case of the switch statement (in which you are receiving a KVP that you weren't expecting,) you could add the incoming key and value to the dictionary so that it could be easily queried later.  Without knowing the specifics of the data you are modeling, it is tough to give you more specific guidance.

Comment: Well, say that I wanted to return a list of objects (instead of Worksite) with only ID each object. ID being the only thing that I know each procedure / view is using. Every single invoke would be using the same parameters, all of the relevant ones are returning a DataSet and I only wish to either serialize or create class instances with ID's in them. 
How would I go about doing that?

Comment: I have modified the answer based on your clarification.

Comment: Honestly great advice there, man! :)
I'll update my question with my the solution I decided on. Feel free to have a look at it and see if you find any potential bottlenecks!

Comment: Thanks!  Your solution looks good, but a dictionary already has a "list" built in... If you are creating a List of Dictionaries that each have one keyvaluepair in them, you can simplify it by either just adding many items to a single dictionary, or by just creating a list of objects - json will create your keys from the variable names without you having to do it explicitly from the column names.  You can try it a few ways and save the json string to a file or view it to make sure it looks like you would expect.  Since you are using reflection, you might look into creating anonymous objects...

Comment: It does look good atm, except for the added "\" in the beginning and trailing after each key and value. :p